# get a small bitmap image from a big bitmap in android

Tags: android, image, graphics, bitmap

Can anybody have any idea about how to get a small bitmap image from a big bitmap which is the combination of many bitmaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a small bitmap.

Create a canvas using that bitmap.

Paste a Rect from the original bitmap to the new one.

Yes, this is annoying; no, you can't skip the pointless canvas step, that's how it works here.

Comment: for more info look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618355/how-to-blit-in-android